# как сменить заводской mac адрес в android 10

Tags: android, root, adb, android-adb

есть андроид 10, есть рут.

делаю так:

```
  ip link set wlan0 address 00:11:22:11:22:11
```

потом так:

```
ifconfig wlan0 | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'
```

и получаю

```
00:11:22:11:22:11
```

но.....
когда перезапускаю устройство... и повторяя

```
ifconfig wlan0 | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'
```

получаю за место

```
00:11:22:11:22:11
```

заводской mac адрес...
как мне сменить заводской mac? где он хранится вообще?